# Constant array types in C, flaw in standard?

Tags: c, standards

Paragraph 6.7.3.8 of the C99 spec states

> If the speciﬁcation of an array type includes any type qualiﬁers, the element type is so-qualiﬁed, not the array type. If the speciﬁcation of a function type includes any type qualiﬁers, the behavior is undeﬁned.

In the [rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) (logical page 87, physical page 94), an example of casting a flat pointer to a (variable length) array pointer is given.

```
void g(double *ap, int n)
{
    double (*a)[n] = (double (*)[n]) ap;
    /* ... */ a[1][2] /* ... */
}
```

Certainly if the array `ap` is not modified within the function, it should be marked const, however the cast in

```
void g(const double *ap, int n)
{
    const double (*a)[n] = (const double (*)[n]) ap;
    /* ... */
}
```

does not preserve the `const` qualifier since (per 6.7.3.8) it applies to the elements of the target instead of the target itself, which has array type `double[n]`.  This means that compilers will rightly complain if given the appropriate flags (`-Wcast-qual` for GCC).  There is no way to denote a `const` array type in C, but this cast is very useful and "correct".  The `-Wcast-qual` flag is useful for identifying misuse of array parameters, but the false positives discourage its use.  Note that indexing `a[i][j]` is both more readable and, with many compilers, produces better machine code than `ap[i*n+j]` since the former allows some integer arithmetic to be hoisted out of inner loops with less analysis.

Should compilers just treat this as a special case, effectively lifting qualifiers from the elements to the array type to determine whether a given cast removes qualifiers or should the spec be amended?  Assignment is not defined for array types, so would it hurt for qualifiers to always apply to the array type rather than just the elements, in contrast to 6.7.3.8?

Comment: It winds me up when `~(logical page N ≡ physical page N)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known issue that has been discussed several times over the last 10 years at comp.std.c. The bottom line is that the specific case you presented is not currently legal in Standard C; you need to either remove the qualifier or refrain from using a pointer to an array to refer to the qualified elements in the array.

If you think you have a good idea to overcome the issue, you can post it to `news:comp.std.c` for discussion. If others agree that it is a good idea, you or someone else can file a defect report to have the behavior changed (there are several committee members that frequent comp.std.c so feedback from the people who would potentially be reviewing the DR would be useful to have prior to filing it). I think there may be some issues with your proposal to have qualifiers affect the array itself, but I'd have to give it some more thought.

Comment: Thanks, I realize I'm not the first person to run into this.  When I searched comp.std.c, I found several cases where people wanted a similar assignment without an explicit cast.  With the cast, I think the example is perfectly safe and standards conforming, although it looks wrong to the compiler.

Comment: C99 added several features to make C more appealing for numerics, especially VLA and restrict.  In lieu of the standard addressing this case, it would be nice if compilers could determine that the cast was actually safe.

Comment: It may be "safe" in the sense that it doesn't works as expected with existing implementations but based on the way the standard is worded today, I think the compilers are correct and this technically isn't valid C code.

Comment: For what it's worth, compilers only complain when special flags are given (-Wcast-qual for GCC, not included in -Wall -Wextra).  Such flags are not available in current Intel and PGI compilers.  My thought was that the spec could make const-lifting precise so the cast would not "look dangerous".

Comment: One issue maybe is that if arrays are qualified by their element qualifiers - what to do for rvalue arrays? Rvalues are not qualified, but if that's so, and if an rvalue array has a const element type, then in those cases an element type would *not* affect the array qualifiers. This is very nasty, and actually we have a similar situation in C++: Some compilers (those based on EDG), strip qualifiers from array elements if the array is an rvalue: `struct A { char const c[5]; A():c() { } }; int main() { A().c[0] = 'a'; }` <- this is valid on those implementations.

Comment: Because C++ says that the same as C - that cv qualifiers applied to an array qualify the elements instead of the array. But then, it says that an array type can be said to be "more or less qualified" than other types based on its element type. This is actually quite tricky, i think.

Comment: Am I missing something obvious, or doesn't the following declaration/cast do exactly what Jed wants?

`double (* const a)[n] = (double (* const)[n]) ap;`

It works on my compiler (trying to write `a=value` is an error), but I suppose my compiler could just be ignoring the spec.

Comment: @MichaelGraczyk No, that is a `const` pointer to a mutable array (`a[i][j] = 0.0` is allowed with your version). I want a pointer to `const` data. Note that `gcc -Wcast-qual` warns that your version discards the `const` qualified from pointer target type.

Answer (score 1):

Possible workaround for the C programmer (but not the compiler designer):

gcc with `-Wcast-qual` does not complain about this:

```
void g(const double *ap, int n)
{
    int i;
    struct box 
    {
      double a[n];
    };
    const struct box *s = (const struct box *)ap;

    for (i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
       doStuffWith(s->a[i]);
       /* ... */
    }
}
```

Even if it's not very elegant.  The trailing array member `a` also has a slightly different meaning between C89 and C99, but at least you get the intended effect.

Comment: It would actually look like `s[i].a[j]` which the compiler could probably optimize in the same way as `a[i][j]`.  This solution avoids the warning, but it adds significant obfuscation, particularly for 4-dimensional arrays which I use.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is awkward with pointers (ie, arrays), but here's my recollection of the details:

`const double *ap` is a pointer to a constant double;

`double *const ap` is a constant pointer to a double;

`const double *const ap` is a constant pointer to a constant double;

So I believe it is possible to do what you're asking, although I've not tried this in years -- the `gcc` option you're using wasn't available the last time I did this!

EDIT:  This answer is not correct for the question - I'm leaving it to preserve the comments below, which clarify the problem for mere mortals (or rusty C developers...)

Comment: My C is rusty, but why doesn't `const double *const ap` in the method signature do exactly what he's requesting?  Constant array reference and Constant Element references?

Comment: No, the consts in the example all refer to the elements, not the pointers.  A quirk of the language (or compiler?) makes it look as though the const qualifier on the elements is not preserved, when logically it is preserved.

Comment: The second `const` is irrelevant since we don't care about changing the value of the pointer `ap`.  We want to cast a "pointer to const double" to "pointer to const array of double" this cannot be expressed in C so instead we cast to "pointer to array of const double" which triggers the warning.

Comment: > the gcc option you're using wasn't available the last time I did this

BTW, -Wcast-qual has been in gcc at least since 2.5.8 (1993).

Comment: @Jed - Should give you a hint as to the last time I did this!  Seriously, it probably was some time in the mid- to late- 90s, so support of 2.5.8 or earlier for our products at the time is very likely.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: as far as C is concerned pointers and arrays are indistinguishable -- increment a pointer, and you get the next offset - just like a[0] to a[1].  The original [] syntax is syntactic sugar, and more recent compilers take advantage of the syntax as noted above.

Comment: @KenGentle: That doesn't mean that pointers are arrays, or that an array type is identical to a pointer type. Neither is true.