# Report warning when apply container_of macro to embedded char array

Tags: c, gcc, macros, gcc-warning

When I apply `container_of` macro to a C struct which contains an array of char, I got **warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type**.

Here is the codes:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({          \
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
    (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})


struct st {
    int a;
    char b;
    char c[16];
    void *p;
};

int main(void)
{
    struct st t = {
        .a = 101,
        .b = 'B',
        .c = "hello",
        .p = NULL
    };

    char (*p)[16] = &t.c;
    struct st *s = container_of(p, struct st, c);

    return 0;
}
```

It seems that the type of `__mptr` is `[]`, which is deduced by `typeof()`. However, `ptr` itself is type `(*)[]`. Obviously, they are not the same.

Besides, if I compile this code by **clang**, everything is OK. GCC seems have a more strict rule for type checking.

Q: How to correct this warning?

Comment: Your error message should include the actual types. And `(*)[]` is not a type, nor is `[]`.

Comment: thx for your response, here `[]` stands for array type, and `(*)[]` stands for pointer to array.

Comment: I have difficulty believing that clang accepts this code.  At minimum, it is relying on an extension to do so.  The macro expands to a parenthesized block of code, and that is not an expression -- it does not represent a value at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, it's relying on two GCC extensions. This macro definition comes from the Linux kernel, I believe (at least it is currently used in the Linux kernel). The equivalent macro in the Windows NT headers is `CONTAINING_RECORD`, which doesn't use any GCC extensions, of course.

Comment: The `container_of` macro from the Linux kernel is somewhat deficient, but if you have to use it, and you know the member is an array, you can use an element of the array instead of the array itself. I.e. `char *p = &t.c[0]; struct st *s = container_of(p, struct st, c[0]);`

Comment: Interestingly, the Linux kernel's `container_of` macro is basically unchanged since it first appeared (in "include/linux/kernel.h") in Linux kernel version 2.5.28.

Answer (score 1):

The declartion of `__mptr` is unuseful, since it is simply cast to `char*` in the next line. Just replace the macro with:

```
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ((type *)((char *)(ptr) - offsetof(type, member)))
```

**Note:** GCC 6.2.0 didn't give any warning for the original code, unless for the unused variable `s`.

Answer (score 1):

An array type is itself not `const`, the `const`ness is actually from each individual member being `const`. There is actually no syntax allowing you to declare that an array itself is `const`. You can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/305293/315052) for additional details.

It seems, however, that the `typeof` macro extension in GCC is flawed in that if `typeof` resolves to an array type, the `const` qualifier applies to the array rather than to its individual members. ([André Sassi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39961913/315052) has noted this issue seems to have been resolved in a newer version of GCC.)

I don't know what you would consider an acceptable workaround, but the following compiles without the noted warning.

```
const struct st *ct = &t;
typeof(ct->c) *p = &ct->c;
struct st *s = container_of(p, struct st, c);
```

Comment: If the `const` is the only problem then simply removing it should be a viable option, since the `const`ness is immediately cast away.  The only reason I can think of for it is to handle the case where the macro's `ptr` argument is a pointer to the `const`-qualified version of the referenced type, but even then, André Sassi's suggestion seems more appropriate.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: My suggestion only applies if changing the macro definition is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the member being passed to `container_of` is an array, you can pass an element of that array instead to avoid the warning:

```
char *p = &t.c[0]; /* or: char *p = t->c; */
struct st *s = container_of(p, struct st, c[0]);
```

Another way to avoid the warning is to make the pointer a pointer to `void`:

```
void *p = &t.c;
struct st *s = container_of(p, struct st, c);
```

Regarding the original code, it seems the behaviour of GCC changed sometime between GCC 4.9 and GCC 5.4.1. The later version of GCC doesn't produce the warning "incompatible pointer type" for the original code. However, enabling `-Wpedantic` with the later version of GCC produces the warning "pointers to arrays with different qualifiers are incompatible in ISO C [-Wpedantic]".