# What is the purpose of __mptr in latest container_of macro?

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, macros, gcc-plugins

I am reading linux kernel 5.17.5 and now looking at container_of() macro.

```c
/**
 * container_of - cast a member of a structure out to the containing structure
 * @ptr:    the pointer to the member.
 * @type:   the type of the container struct this is embedded in.
 * @member: the name of the member within the struct.
 *
 */
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({              \
    void *__mptr = (void *)(ptr);                   \
    static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) ||   \
              __same_type(*(ptr), void),            \
              "pointer type mismatch in container_of()");   \
    ((type *)(__mptr - offsetof(type, member))); })
```

My question is really simple: What is the purpose of the `__mptr`, can i just replace `__mptr` by `(void *)ptr` like this?

```c
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({          \
    static_assert(__same_type(*(ptr), ((type *)0)->member) ||   \
              __same_type(*(ptr), void),            \
              "pointer type mismatch in container_of()");   \
    ((type *)((void*)ptr - offsetof(type, member))); })
```

Comment: Definitely not `(void *)ptr` but maybe `(void *)(ptr)`. But that will also cause problems as explained in Chen Li's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *“kernel.h: handle pointers to arrays better in container_of()”*, `__mptr` doesn't serve for type checking anymore. It is used to eliminate `scripts/gcc-plugins/randomize_layout_plugin.c`'s informative message like `inform(gimple_location(stmt), "found mismatched ssa struct pointer types: %qT and %qT\n", ptr_lhs_type, ptr_rhs_type);`. One of this file's job is:

```
/*
 * iterate over all statements to find "bad" casts:
 * those where the address of the start of a structure is cast
 * to a pointer of a structure of a different type, or a
 * structure pointer type is cast to a different structure pointer type
 */
```

If `__mptr` is missing, the macro will include code as you said:

`(type *)((void*)ptr - offsetof(type, member)))`

(PS: `char *` is better here, because it is guaranteed by iso c standard to be 1 byte for `offsetof`, `void *` is guaranteed by gnu c only)

If `offsetof` gets zero, and ptr will contain the start address of struct type `member`, then this will be cast to be a totally different type: `struct type *`. This form malfunctions per `scripts/gcc-plugins/randomize_layout_plugin.c` and will be detected by it.

With the introduce of `void *__mptr = (void *)(ptr);`, the compiler doesn't know the type of `__mptr` anymore, so `scripts/gcc-plugins/randomize_layout_plugin.c` will not complain when casting the `void *` `__mptr` to `(type *)`
You can see the  real case and related fixed patch from https://lkml.org/lkml/2017/6/20/873

---

Below is original answer for kernel prior to 4.13 when `__mptr` was used for type checking:

Let's simplify the `container_of` and see this case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#define container_of(ptr, type, member) ({          \
    const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
    (type *)( (char *)__mptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
#define container_of_without_typechecking(ptr, type, member) ({         \
    (type *)( (char *)ptr - offsetof(type,member) );})
struct Foo
{
    int a;
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct Foo foo;
    int *a;

    printf("foo addr: %p\n", &foo);
    a = &foo.a;
    printf("container of a: %p\n", container_of_without_typechecking((unsigned long long*)a, struct Foo, a));
    printf("typecheck: container of a: %p\n", container_of((unsigned long long*)a, struct Foo, a));
    return 0;
}
```

`container_of_without_typechecking` doesn't have `__mptr` but `container_of` does.

When compiling:

```
a.c: In function ‘main’:
a.c:13:55: warning: initialization of ‘const int *’ from incompatible pointer type ‘long long unsigned int *’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   13 |         const typeof( ((type *)0)->member ) *__mptr = (ptr);    \
      |                                                       ^
a.c:28:47: note: in expansion of macro ‘container_of’
   28 |     printf("typecheck: container of a: %p\n", container_of((unsigned long long*)a, struct Foo, a));
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

As you can see, `container_of` throws an `incompatible pointer type` warning while `container_of_without_typechecking` does not, so it just for type checking.

Also, note that the Linux kernel regards this warning as an error:

```
KBUILD_CFLAGS   += $(call cc-option,-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types)
```

So, you will get an **error** instead of a warning if you pass through the wrong type to `container_of`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer:). Before linux-4.13,  kernel use `__mptr` for type checking, but after 4.13, type checking has been moved into `BUILD_BUG_ON_MSG` macro and use `static_assert` for type checking after 5.16. So the `__mptr` is just a history?

Comment: @PuhanZhou `__mptr` since 4.13 is used to eliminate informational message _note: found mismatched ssa struct pointer types: 
'struct f2fs_inode_info' and 'struct inode'_ which _happen for all structures that have a zero offset
between the member and the container structure, i.e. idential
pointers_, you can see from here: https://www.mail-archive.com/linux-kernel@vger.kernel.org/msg1426986.html

Comment: Could you add some details about how `__mptr` is involved in the type checking at all? As it is `void*` it is rather not checking the type. The suggested replacement from the OP does the type checking but without storing the address in a temp variable. I can't really see how the main question is addressed here.

Comment: I'm sorry for that. Pls see my new updates, which explain why `__mptr` is still needed now.

Comment: As a point of interest, the “kernel.h: handle pointers to arrays better in container_of()” patch was definitely submitted as a result of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961293

Comment: And my original version of the "kernel.h: handle pointers to arrays better in container_of()” patch submitted to LKML didn't have the intermediate `__mptr` variable, but that was merged in by Arnd Bergman before the patch made it to Linus's tree (see the msg1426986.html link you posted in the comments above). At least it still has my name on it. :-)  (Maybe I submitted a "v2" patch - I can't remember!)

Comment: I guess the maintainer did this minor change and rebase your patch, which is kind of frequent.

Comment: @ChenLi Indeed, it made sense to combine the two patches into a single commit to make git bisecting easier. (Best to fix broken patches before they get passed upstream! I've done that myself too.)